# Add strings to the end of certain lines in a text document and write to an empty text doc in C#

Tags: c#

I am reading a text file and picking out certain keywords and adding strings to them and then writing it to another empty text document. My problem is that since I am doing this to multiple strings, it writes the text file multiple times over and I end up with 5 additional lines for every line in the original text document. Anyone know another method that I could use to get this done?

```
var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textBox5.Text);
        var outFileContents = new List<string>();
        foreach (var line in fileContents)
        {

            if (line.Contains("Start **** Connect Process"))  //Text to find 
                outFileContents.Add(line + "," + Environment.NewLine + "*****" + Environment.NewLine); //Add your text
            else
                outFileContents.Add(line + ","); //Keep column

            if (line.Contains("Start $$$$$$ Connect Process"))
                outFileContents.Add(line + "," + Environment.NewLine + "$$$$$$" + Environment.NewLine);
            else
                outFileContents.Add(line + ",");
            if (line.Contains("Fail to send &&&&&&&&"))
                outFileContents.Add(line + "," + Environment.NewLine + "&&&&&&" + Environment.NewLine);
            else
                outFileContents.Add(line + ",");

            if (line.Contains("Start @@@@@ Process"))
                outFileContents.Add(line + "," + Environment.NewLine + "@@@@@@" + Environment.NewLine);
            else
                outFileContents.Add(line + ",");
            if (line.Contains("ConnectionStatus: ######"))
                outFileContents.Add(line + "," + Environment.NewLine + "######" + Environment.NewLine);
            else
                outFileContents.Add(line + ",");

            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(textBox6.Text, outFileContents);
        }



        Process.Start(textBox6.Text);

    }
```

Comment: Just move the call to `WriteAllLines` to *after* the `foreach` loop.

Comment: To everybody I downvoted: `WriteAllLines` *overwrites the file.* That's not the problem, although I agree he should move it out of the loop for efficiency.

Comment: @JonSkeet: No, that's not the problem.

Comment: @JimMischel: Ah, yes - I'd say it's *a* problem (it's definitely not the code you want) but it's not the cause of the issue in question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't because you're calling `WriteAllLines` in a loop. `WriteAllLines` *overwrites the file*. Just see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The problem is that you're adding every line to the output list five times.

What you have is essentially:

```
for every line
    if ()
        add modified line
    else
        add unmodified line

    if ()
        add modified line
    else
        add unmodified line
```

Five of those conditionals means five copies of the line being added to the output list.

You need to build your string in a temporary buffer and add it to the list just once. Something like:

```
for(...)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line);

    if (line.Contains("Start **** Connect Process"))
        sb.Append("," + Environment.NewLine + "*****" + Environment.NewLine);
    else
        sb.Append(',');

    // do that for each of your conditionals.

    // and finally, add the line to the output buffer:
    outFileContents.Add(sb.ToString());
}
```

Now, you should remove the `WriteAllLines` out of the loop so that you're not rewriting the file every time. So your code becomes:

```
for (....)
{
    // do stuff
}
File.WriteAllLines(...)
```

Comment: Just for my knowledge, how does the Append function work? Before I was adding the new strings to the existing in line and writing each of those lines so thats why I was get 5 copies? And Append just changes the line without writing it?

Comment: The code is creating a `StringBuilder`, where the modified line is constructed. `Append` just adds data to that. The constructed line is then added to the `outFileContents` after you've made the modifications. Before, you were calling `outFileContents.Add` five times, which is why you were getting five copies. Now you're just calling `outFileContents.Add` one time.

Answer (score 0):

get   this `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(textBox6.Text, outFileContents);`  out of foreach

```
 var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textBox5.Text);
            var outFileContents = new List<string>();
            foreach (var line in fileContents)
            {




            }
     System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(textBox6.Text, outFileContents);


            Process.Start(textBox6.Text);

        }
```

Comment: That's not the problem. `WriteAllLines` overwrites the file. See the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you're writing the text over and over (it's in a loop). Instead you need to write to the file just once at the end of your operation by moving the `WriteAllLines` method call.

Additionally you might want to think about using the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for generating your contents.

```
var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textBox5.Text);
    var outFileContents = new List<string>();
    foreach (var line in fileContents)
    {

        if (line.Contains("Start **** Connect Process"))  //Text to find 
            outFileContents.Add(line + "," + Environment.NewLine + "*****" + Environment.NewLine); //Add your text
        else
            outFileContents.Add(line + ","); //Keep column

        if (line.Contains("Start $$$$$$ Connect Process"))
            outFileContents.Add(line + "," + Environment.NewLine + "$$$$$$" + Environment.NewLine);
        else
            outFileContents.Add(line + ",");
        if (line.Contains("Fail to send &&&&&&&&"))
            outFileContents.Add(line + "," + Environment.NewLine + "&&&&&&" + Environment.NewLine);
        else
            outFileContents.Add(line + ",");

        if (line.Contains("Start @@@@@ Process"))
            outFileContents.Add(line + "," + Environment.NewLine + "@@@@@@" + Environment.NewLine);
        else
            outFileContents.Add(line + ",");
        if (line.Contains("ConnectionStatus: ######"))
            outFileContents.Add(line + "," + Environment.NewLine + "######" + Environment.NewLine);
        else
            outFileContents.Add(line + ",");
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(textBox6.Text, outFileContents);

    Process.Start(textBox6.Text);
```

Comment: That's not the problem. `WriteAllLines` overwrites the file. See the documentation.